# onNext of a created Observable does not work

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android

I am learning how to use Observable.create(). so i created the below posted example. but when I run the App. and click the button the log statement in the 
onNext is never displayed. and i receive the following message:

```
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

please let me know how to do it the corret way.

**code**:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private Button btnStart = null;
    private TextView tvText = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        this.btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        this.tvText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvText);

        final int[] i = {0};
        //how to create emitter from a worker thread.
        Observable.create(emitter -> {
            btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    emitter.onNext(Log.i(TAG, "i: " + i[0]++));
                }
            });
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you consume this `Observable`? The code shown barely does anything so it is unlikely you get the warning for this piece of code.

Comment: @akarnokd i modified the code..i posted the entire class. please have a look at it

Comment: Where do you subscribe to it?

Comment: @akarnokd i ahve seen a tutorial..and he didnt do that? pelase let me know how to correct it

Comment: What tutorial? Also when you don't even subscribe to it, I don't think it is possible you get that "too much work" error/warning; unless you still haven't provided the **actual code** you are having trouble with.

Comment: @akarnokd ok..now i subscribed and it works...but since inside oncreate i have access to emitter.next, why do i neeed to subscribe. inside the observer i have also onNext. what is the difference between them

Comment: You have to subscribe to an `Observable` to get it running, otherwise nothing happens to your chain of operators.

Comment: @akarnokd thanks..but what if i want to create observable from a non UI thread? is it possible

Comment: Observables themselves are thread-agnostic. I'm not sure what you mean.